# swift - Popover is not displayed correctly in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, popover

Popover takes the complete screen when displayed in landscape mode, it works correctly in portrait mode though. Also, it is does not disappear when i click outside the popover in landscape mode.

I connected the popover through the storyboard. Inside the popoverviewcontroller I placed a view which contains the buttons. The code for the viewdidload() of the popoverviewcontroller is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.preferredContentSize = popoverView.frame.size
        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Portrait:

[image]

landscape:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`to your class like this:

**swift 3**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    ...
```

As a second step, add the following function:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

**Explanation:** By returning  UIModalPresentationStyle as none, the original presentation style is kept and your popover is not streched to the bottom of your screen in landscape orientation.

Comment: this doesn't work. In landscape mode it still presents modally.

Comment: @Ruben See the answer from Markv07. The `traitCollection: UITraitCollection` parameter of the `adaptivePresentationStyle` function is necessary for it to work. Clearly a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 13):

The answer from @Jake2Finn works for **Swift 4.0**.

The trait parameter specifically is required to fix the landscape problem:

```
traitCollection: UITraitCollection
```

Without it the function adaptive... only works for portrait.

Comment: I was a little confused by this description, but it's simply that there are two adaptivePresentationStyle  methods in UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, and you must implement the one which takes the traitCollection parameter - implementing the plain adaptivePresentationStyle method won't fix the problem.